# Remove Intersect from query , use inner join instead of it and result should be union with third one

Tags: sql, inner-join, intersect

I have following Query ,

```
(select student_id from student where std = 8)
intersect
(select student_id from student where std = 7)
intersect
(select student_id from student where std = 9)
union
(select student_id from student where std = 10)
```

Now, I do not want to use `intersect` , instead of it I want to use `inner join`

So I convert that query to following

```
select * from
(
(select student_id from student where std = 8)
as res1 inner join
(select student_id from student where std = 9)
as res2 on res1.student_id = res2.student_id inner join
(select student_id from student where std = 7)
as res3 on res2.student_id = res3.student_id
)
union
(select student_id from student where std = 10)
```

In this case I got following error:

> All queries combined using a UNION, INTERSECT or EXCEPT operator must
>   have an equal number of expressions in their target lists.

Answer (score 1):

Because you joined, and you use `SELECT *` , the query returns records in the format

```
STUDENT_ID | STUDENT_ID
```

And the second query returns only 1 column.

Use this:

```
select t.student_id
from student t
inner join student s
 ON(t.student_id = s.student_id)
WHERE s.std = 9 and t.std = 8
UNION
select student_id from student where std = 10
```

Comment: In this case i got following error : 
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'.

Comment: I don't even have `as` here, so it doesn't really make sense. @QuestionWarriors

Comment: I have edited question , Suppose there is 2 intersect & 1 union then? @sagi

Comment: Note the above JOIN is not the same as INTERSECT, it may return more rows. But with UNION result is the same.

Comment: Okay Got it, So what changes should i made to achieve result with more than one intersect.? And result should be union with other table.?

Answer (score 0):

Probably there is a difference between columns.
When yuo use UNION the columns selected must be the same,
you have * in the first select and student_id in the last (under union).